# Securing my website with API keys in Local Storage

Tags: html, mysql, web-services, security

I was intending to release a website to the public that stored sensitive information on the client side using Local Storage such as API keys. Variables stored in Local Storage are used in my PHP scripts.

I was thinking, since it had an SSL certificate, this would suffice for storing sensitive information such as an API key and secret.

My website will not have ads. The website also has a MySQL database.

I am going to configure a general user for reading data in since a user does not need write privileges (it is a read-only site). The problem is if they went on a malicious website later on, they could extract these Local Storage keys (maybe with a script) and potentially hack my consumer.

The names are very generic on my website when creating and using the keys so it would be hard to identify the origin of the keys or what their purpose is.

Is this wrong to do this to my consumer?

Comment: "since it had an SSL certificate" Many people think SSL will protect against hacking attacks.. But SSL only encrypts/decryptes the data between server and client(s).. Meaning attacks like SQL injection, cross side scripting and others will still work.

Comment: @hbennet3 there's definitely a problem, here, but I think a piece that's missing here is what do the API keys actually allow, and what is their scope?  Are these keys to *your* API, and are they scoped to the specific user?

Comment: no these are api keys to various websites. I make calls back to their api's using these websites's api keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is wrong. It means a huge security leak. Imagine the case when any malicious Javascript is executed in the browser for any reason. It will be able to read the content of localStorage and send it to the hacker.

This could be caused by a website problem, such as possibility of XSS injection, but a browser extension with malicious content can achieve the same. While XSS injection can be protected against, if the developers of the site are careful, what browser extensions the users will install is beyond your control. Avoid this approach. Store sensitive data safely on the server.

Comment: So my website is built on ajax. After api keys are received from the user they simply click the on button on a webpage and everything is handled for them. They receive changes made out onto the webpage. Would it also be in bad practice once the page is loaded that they will remain on for the duration of their stay to store these variables are session variables even? Or do I need to make a request every time to retrieve the api keys from the database?

Comment: @hbennet3 it is an extremely bad thing to keep secret data in Javascript variables, but you can keep frequently queried data in server-side session. Sensitive data should not be sent out to the browser, as the browser can be unsafe. If you keep sensitive data on server-side, then in case the browser is hacked, the hacker will be able to impersonate the user at your site, but unable to get any other sensitive information and when the session is destroyed, the user will retain his or her user even if the session was destroyed.

Comment: @hbennet3 also, when the user changes his or her password, you will need to ask him or her to enter the old password in order to avoid excluding your users from their own accounts even in the case when their browser is hacked. However, there is nothing wrong to store frequently loaded data in session variables at the server side (and not at the client), however, I advise you not to do so until it becomes a necessity.

Comment: so would something more safe in practice be to do the following... Have my user log in to the website and after successfully logging in store into SESSION variables their api keys in my PHP script and maintain that session throughout?

Comment: @hbennet3 it is much safer than storing those values in localStorage, but not as safe as querying the database. However, this is an intelligent compromise if you need it. If my answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it.